# Generate a string of "|" width the same size of another string in a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple of spans with strings in latin ltr, I want to clone those strings in rtl with a placeholder string like "|".."||||||"...

Example:

```
<span>Lorem impus dolor sit amen</span>
```

I want to generate another span with the same innerWidth than the previous span, the final span should look like this one

```
<span>||||||||||||||||||||||||||</span>
```

I'm using this jQuery code but I can't get the same size for most of the strings

```
$('elem').find('span').each(function() {

    var char_width = function(char, elem) {
        var span = $('<span />').html(char);
        $(elem).append(span);
        var width = span.width();
        span.remove();
        return width;
    };

    var char_length = char_width('¦', this);
    var original_width = char_width($(this).text(), this);
    var nbchars = Math.floor(original_width / char_length);
    var chars = Array(nbchars).join('¦');
    while (char_width(chars, this) > original_width) chars = chars.slice(0, -1);
    var diff = original_width - char_width(chars, this);
    $(this).html(chars).css('padding-left', diff);

});
```

And just to mention, this script is taking more than 2000ms to finish the execution.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: RESOLVED
The key of this is not replacing spaces, here is the code

```
var placeholder = $(this).text().split(/\s+/);
for (var a in placeholder) placeholder[a] = new Array(placeholder[a].length + 1).join('_');
placeholder = placeholder.join(' ');
```

Comment: Different characters are different widths.  Your code seems to expect all characters to be the same width.  Use a mono-spaced font or look at the width of the entire rendered string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a monospace font and do something along the lines of:

```
new Array( someString.length + 1 ).join('|');
```

Here's a small demo I came up with: http://jsbin.com/jewurewo/2/edit

Comment: That does not work it's even much smaller, "abcdef" does not have the same innerWidth than "|||||||" it's larger

Comment: Use a monospace font. ;)

Comment: I've tried that and here is the result http://awesomescreenshot.com/02d2n7ex59 I'm tring to make it look like that http://awesomescreenshot.com/06c2n7f074

Comment: Here you go, responsive and everything: http://jsbin.com/jewurewo/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jewurewo/4/ In this code you, the first line in .right, 'Lorem impus' is in the left and 'dolor sit amen' is in the right, while it should be the inverse because I'm using this for a plateforme of translation "English"->"Arabic", and Arabic is an RTL language

Comment: Thanks Man ! I found it :) the key is not replacing spaces

var placeholder = $(this).text().split(/\s+/);
for (var a in placeholder) placeholder[a] = new Array(placeholder[a].length + 1).join('_');
placeholder = placeholder.join(' ');

Answer (score 0):

Try using a repeating background image on an element with invisible text:

```
<span style="color: transparent; background-image: url('pipe.png')">Lorem impus dolor sit amen</span>
```

Comment: I've already tried that, strings are not ordred in RTL they are just aligned in right

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just looped over all the `span` elements and for each one I created a new empty `span` and added bars to it until its width was larger or equal to the original `span`'s width:

**The code works for any font:**

## Sans-Serif Test




## Monospace Test

Main loop:

```
while(newSpan.width() < elem.width())
    newSpan.append('|');
```

The code is commented, Have fun!